# how to define RMSE as function in Python

Tags: python

I have one set of observed data and I am calculating several sets of computed data and then trying to find out the RMS error between observed and computed. I have to define the RMS error as a function because it will be used in a optimization code where it will be treated as function. Now, as the RMS error needs summation and then mean, so we need to initialize it as, say, sum=0 and then sum=sum+ AAA (say). But I don't understand how I can do this in Python after defining it as 'function'. The code is as below

```
import math

import numpy as np

def computed (z):

     return (constant*z)/(z**2+(x-x0)**2)

observed=[]

with open ('observed_data.txt') as finp:

     lines=finp.readlines()

     size=100

     observed=[0]*size

     i=0

     for line in lines:

          i=i+1

          observed[i]= float(line)

  def error(z):

     for i in range (1, 100, 1):

          x=i

          return math.sqrt(((computed(z)-observed[i])**2)
```

Here, how to initialize the error to have the sum of all 100 errors to compute the mean? It would be easy it is just one calculation of rms error. But as it has to be defined as function, I am facing the problem.

Comment: Can you please check the indentation, particularly of the `return` in the final `for` loop`?

Comment: Also, you will have to pass `x` to computed. And what is `x0`?

Comment: x0 is a fixed number, which I am giving at the beginning (not shown here). I am giving the value of x as x=i in for loop. That will work for x, right? I don't want to define computed as a function of x.